# MySQL multiple related permission per one user in the same result possible?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequalize in a nodeJs application. I have an entity with a one to may relation (user to many permissions).

I have the following sequalise query to get all users with their permissions... but i think i have been in nosql land for too long :/ and i fear my head no longer works in this way...

```
models.User.findAll( {
            raw: true,
            include: [ {
                model: models.UserPermissions,
                required: false
            } ],
            logging: console.log
        } ).then(function( users ) {
            deferred.resolve( users );
        }, function(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        });
```

Produces the following mysql query:

```
SELECT
    `User`.`id`,
    `User`.`username`,
    `User`.`password`,
    `User`.`reset_password_token` AS `resetPasswordToken`,
    `User`.`reset_password_expires` AS `resetPasswordExpires`,
    `User`.`created_at`, `User`.`updated_at`,
    `UserPermissions`.`id` AS `UserPermissions.id`,
    `UserPermissions`.`user_id` AS `UserPermissions.user_id`,
    `UserPermissions`.`permission` AS `UserPermissions.permission`,
    `UserPermissions`.`created_at` AS `UserPermissions.created_at`,
    `UserPermissions`.`updated_at` AS `UserPermissions.updated_at`
FROM
    `user` AS `User`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `user_permissions` AS `UserPermissions` 
    ON `User`.`id` = `UserPermissions`.`user_id`;
```

The result of course is not what I am no used with NoSQL. Instead of recieving one object containing the user and also an array of documents within containing the related permissions I get multiple results for the same user but with different permissions.

See the snapshot of the result set below (I have 2 users in the users table, and 3 permissions in the permissions table).

[image]

Is it possible with sequalise, or even mysql for that matter, to return one object for a user with a sub array of their pemissions? or will this really require another query and post query match up?

HACKY FIX:

```
models.User.findAll( {
            raw: true,
            include: [ {
                model: models.UserPermissions,
                required: false
            } ]
        } ).then(function( users ) {

            var newUsersObj = {};

            for( var i = 0 ; i < users.length ; ++i ){
                if( newUsersObj[users[i].id] ){
                    newUsersObj[users[i].id].permissions.push( users[i]['UserPermissions.permission'] );
                } else {
                    newUsersObj[users[i].id] = users[i];
                    newUsersObj[users[i].id].permissions = [ users[i]['UserPermissions.permission'] ];
                }
            }

            deferred.resolve( newUsersObj );
        }, function(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        });
```

Comment: no, that's not how sql works. you'll get "repeated" data like that, one row for every `join` created by your query. you could use something like `group_concat()` to "collapse" multiple row values into a single field, but that's not reliable - group_concat can/will silently truncate results that are too long, and then you still have to tear apart that string in your client to get at the individual values again anyways.

Comment: @MarcB  Thanks, this is what i thought too. Shame, though. And i bet there is a way in sequalise to handle this automatically... burried somewhere in the docs :)

Comment: Silly way: request `User` and `UserPermissions`. By js-code: reduce second result by `user_id` and join to first result. I think that result code will be no longer.

Comment: i'm not totally sure i follow Aikon?